# connect usb-c headphones

Tags: usb, audio, alsa

I have a piece of headphones with a USB-C jack. They're the ones that came with the Google Pixel 3. I'm using Archlinux and I'd love to use them with the USB-C jack on my notebook. However, I don't know what steps I need to undertake to make it work.

Here's what I did so far.

- `lsusb` shows the device: `Bus 003 Device 005: ID 18d1:5033 Google Inc.`
- `dmesg` shows when the device is being connected:

```
     [ 2520.298434] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
     [ 2520.694851] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=5033, bcdDevice= 0.20
     [ 2520.694857] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
     [ 2520.694861] usb 3-1: Product: Pixel USB-C earbuds
     [ 2520.694864] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Google
     [ 2520.694867] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 00000089MAJ24397
```

However, `aplay -l` does not show any device that is reflecting my headphones. From this, I assume that the problem is ALSA not recognizing the new USB device as a pair of headphones. I would assume that I now have to edit some ALSA config file to teach ALSA about this device.

How can I find out what exactly I need to edit in which file to make ALSA discover my headphones?

**EDIT**

It seems like a full system update has magically resolved the issue and the buds now work out-of-the box. All help posted here is highly appreciated though for future reference.

Comment: use script alsa-info.sh to get full information about ALSA. may help to locate where problem may be

Comment: here's the output: 
http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=8074953c57b6f94c6b0c2a663acd0a45308cdef5
from what I see, the earbuds are recognized as a whole different sound card (probably because of their internal digital analog converter?), which then raises the question of "how to I tell pulseaudio to route audio via this "sound card"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please connect the earbuds to the computer and run this command:

```
lsusb -d 18d1:5033 -v | grep Class
```

If the output includes the words `Audio` and `Streaming` anywhere, there is hope: the earbuds have a built-in DAC and may be recognizable as a standard USB audio device.

But if that word is not visible, it might be that the only digital electronics in the earbuds is a tiny chip that basically tells "I'm a set of USB-C passive earbuds; feel free to connect specific USB-C pins directly to an analog audio output." And as the standard for  was not finished by the time the USB-C earbuds were released to the market, there seems to be a few competing solutions.

Essentially, the headphones may be directly wired to specific pins in the USB-C connector, and the controlling device needs to be able to switch those pins to analog audio output mode. The USB-C controller of your smartphone can clearly do that; but I very much doubt that many notebooks have the necessary wiring between the audio chip and the USB-C controller to route the analog audio signal out of USB-C.

See also: https://www.reviewgeek.com/11101/dont-bother-with-usb-c-headphones-for-now/

If the USB device information does include the `Audio` class and the `Streaming` subclass, then the `snd-usb-audio` module should be getting loaded. If it works correctly, the audio device should get listed in `/proc/asound/cards`; after that, the only remaining problem might be getting a correct PulseAudio profile assigned to the device (if you are using PulseAudio that is).

But if the `snd-usb-audio` module fails to use the device, then it might have some hardware quirks that need to be accounted for; the module already has a number of quirk options you can try. In this case, and particularly if you find that adding a specific quirk option makes the device work, you should also email the `lsusb -v` output of the device and a description of your findings to the Linux audio driver developers, so that the right quirk(s) will get automatically applied to your device model in future kernel versions.

If your distribution uses PulseAudio and it does not see your device after all these checks, there's one more thing that could be wrong: assigning the right PulseAudio profile to the device. The profiles are located at `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/` directory (at least on Debian/Ubuntu), and the `default.conf` profile has very descriptive comments in it. You might find that one of the non-default profiles is applicable to your device, or you might have to write a new profile.

To assign a particular PulseAudio profile to an audio device, you can use a udev rule. It should be something like:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="sound", <conditions to match only your device>, ENV{PULSE_PROFILE_SET}="profilename.conf"
```

Comment: Here's the output: ´
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Control Device
      bInterfaceClass 1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass 2 Streaming
      bInterfaceClass 1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass 2 Streaming
      bInterfaceClass 1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass 2 Streaming
      bInterfaceClass 1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass 2 Streaming
      bInterfaceClass 1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass 2 Streaming
      bInterfaceClass 3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass 0´

Comment: Good, it looks like standard USB Audio device. It even has interface class 1, subclass 1 which matches the very first and most generic module autoload alias the `snd-usb-audio.ko` module has. So run `lsmod |grep snd_usb_audio` after plugging in the earbuds to see if the module has been autoloaded successfully. Also run `dmesg` and see the tail end of the listing for any error messages; it might be that the earbuds fail because they have some hardware quirks that need to be dealt with.

Comment: Output of "lsmod | grep snd_usb_audio":

snd_usb_audio 278528 2
snd_usbmidi_lib 40960 1 snd_usb_audio
media 61440 5 videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
snd_hwdep 20480 2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm 135168 9 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd 110592  24 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi

Comment: for "dmesg": after what's shown in the original question, I have this:
[ 378.554983] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[ 378.567002] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[ 378.567003] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[ 378.770958] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[ 378.798028] input: Google Pixel USB-C earbuds as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.3/0003:18D1:5033.0001/input/input30
[ 378.851717] hid-generic 0003:18D1:5033.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Google Pixel USB-C earbuds] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1/input3

Comment: It's good that an update fixed it; I guess whatever information was missing to properly detect your device was added by the update. Anyway, I added some more things to check to make this answer more useful for similar questions in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to telcoM for the tip about `snd-usb-audio`.  Turns out my kernel had disabled `SND_USB_AUDIO`.  I used:

```
make menuconfig
```

to set `SND_USB_AUDIO` to `m` (kernel module).  I then checked out my kernel version based on `/proc/version`.  I then recompiled just the kernel modules via:

```
make modules
```

I then inserted the modules in order:

```
sudo insmod sound/core/snd-rawmidi.ko
sudo insmod sound/usb/snd-usbmidi-lib.ko
sudo insmod sound/usb/snd-usb-audio.ko
```

Of course, just rebuilding my kernel and modules together is a better idea as the modules won't be auto loaded on reboot, but the above worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me it now works out of the box

```
Linux ux370a 5.10.16-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat, 13 Feb 2021 20:50:18 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```